# Strange reputation on photo.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation

I have noticed one user on photo.stackexchange.com that has more than 100 in reputation but no answers and no questions - how is that possible?

Comment: Can you link to the user? It's difficult to say without a link to the user in question.

Comment: Here is one :)
http://photo.stackexchange.com/users/155/joel-spolsky

Answer (score 9):

There's a +100 rep bonus for linking accounts, with a [requirement of 200 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50508/no-bonus-points-on-linking-the-accounts/50519#50519) on another site.  Your accounts are [already linked](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/81?tab=accounts#tab-top), but you don't have the necessary rep.  Read more on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-accounts).

Answer (score 3):

If you link to existing stackexchange/stackoverflow account(s), you'll get 100 rep points.

Maybe there's some other option that will also increase reputation without getting upvoted?

Comment: How can I link to existing account ?

Comment: That should be a new question.

Comment: @Imageree: Should be covered on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), but sorry I don't have a link handy.  If you use the same OpenIDs, it should be nearly automatic, as I recall, though. @gabr: Upvoted questions/answers subsequently deleted (without a rep recalc) would also do it, but that's going to be relatively rare.

Comment: I use the same OpenId for all sites and I didn't get any extra points for that.

Comment: @Roger: This should be a new answer.
@Imageree: Post a new question about account linking so that we can find an answer to that.

Comment: @Imageree I've asked & answerred your question to serve as a reference: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/116/why-dont-i-get-the-100-rep-bonus-for-linking-my-accounts

Comment: @Edd: Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

*Just to clear up gabrs answer.*

If you have an account in *any* of the stackexchange websites with 200+ rep (Specifically StackExchange 2.0 websites that were created through Area51)  if you login with that same id on another SE website, it will associate your account and give you +100 rep.

Quote from Jeff Atwoods Answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/award-account-association-bonus-automatically-upon-reaching-200-rep)
"The feature is intended for experienced users who have already reached this threshold, and are now proceeding to new sites in the network.

That way they aren't "noobs" on the new site, they have 101 rep and can use all the core functions"