# Why don't I get the +100 rep bonus for linking my accounts

Tags: support, reputation, faq-suggestion

*Following the discussion [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/strange-reputation-on-photo-stackexchange-com/70#70), I've created a question and answer to serve as a reference for the future. I've tagged it* `[faq-suggestion]` *as I think we probably need to include something about this in our FAQs when we go public.*

I've used the same OpenID for all of my accounts on Stackexchange and The Trilogy sites, but I haven't got the +100 rep bonus I've heard talked about. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have 200 reputation on *one* of the sites you're a member of in order to get the +100 reputation bonus when linking accounts, as outlined by Jeff [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/).

Comment: Hmm, it didn't happen for me. I have well over 200 rep here but when I created a Stack Overflow account I'm stuck at 1 over there, even after clicking the "join accounts" button here.

Comment: That's probably because this site is not yet out of beta and is not yet a full member of the StackExchange community.

Comment: It did work for me, as it has done with all other sites I'm a member of. Post on meta.SO with a `[bug]` tag?